# Hyphenation in nomenclature

Tags: hyphenation, nomenclature

I'm using the `nomecl` package for explaining symbols. However, manual hyphenation rules   like `Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis` for long german words in the description are not working. See the following example:

```
\nomenclature[e187]{$\mathbf{w}$}{Gewichtungsvektor blabla blabla blabla mit maximalem Kontrast/Rausch"=Verhältnis}`
```

gives

[image]

where the `"=` is not interpreted.

Comment: I suspect it's because `"` is a makeindex special character. You may need to do `""` to escape it or use a different command to do the manual hyphenation.

Comment: Thx! This works!

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Why does `"-` work? Does `nomencl` explicitly recognize that as a babel shorthand?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi If `"-` expands to something that doesn't contain a double-quote character then it won't bother `makeindex`. I don't know if `nomencl` tries to perform any checks for `makeindex` characters. (`glossaries` does, but the substitutions only work if the definitions are made in the preamble before those characters are made active by `babel`. Any definitions made in the `document` environment may work if the problematic characters aren't in the label or sort key.)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'm not sure it is a duplicate since the other question wasn't specifically about `nomencl` (although one of the answers covers it).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thank you. Regarding the dub: The OP commented on both answers that he was referring to hyphenation in `nomencl`. I asked him to clarify his questions and worked out an answer but meanwhile the OP created a second question. That's why I think it is doubled. But you could write your comments as an answer and I'll pull back my close-vote

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Okay, I'll write an answer, but I think this question ought to state that it's a follow-up to the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Converting my comment into an answer.)

`makeindex` has its own set of special characters (independent of TeX's special characters). These are typically: `"` (escape), `@` (actual), `!` (level) and `|` (format). If an indexed term contains any of these characters they need to be escaped using `makeindex`'s escape character. So in this case you need to do `""` to indicate a single-double quote character. Like this:

```
Kontrast/Rausch""=Verhältnis
```

(Whereas you would need to do `"!` for an exclamation mark, etc.)

These characters can be changed via a `makeindex` style file.